# SonarQube unit test tool

Tags: testing, nunit, mstest, code-coverage, sonarqube

I want to use unit test tool and measure code coverage with SonarQube.

Which plug in make code coverage for MsTest for SonarQube?

How does SonarQube make code coverage for Nunit?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only way to include unit test metrics for .net code in SonarQube is to use the [sonar-dotnet-gallio plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/231735317)

There are plans to directly support NUnit ([SONARDOTNT-372](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARDOTNT-372)) and MSTest ([SONARDOTNT-357](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARDOTNT-357)) reports in v2.2 of the .net plugins, but that is not available yet.